# i tag click event is not working in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, onclick, internet-explorer-11

```
     <button type="button" class="btn cms-btn-contorls">
                <i class="fas fa-play" onclick="playBannerVideo(this);"></i>
                @*<i class="fas fa-pause" style="display:none;"></i>*@
            </button>

  function playBannerVideo(e) {
            console.log(e);
            $(e).hide();
            $(".cms-banner-text").hide();
            var $vid = $("#cms-video");
            $vid.attr("controls", true);
            var vid = document.getElementById("cms-video");
            vid.play();
        }
```

Please open bellow link and check home page banner video is not working in internet explore 11 but it's working in chrome and Edge properly.

https://smart-structures-dev.azurewebsites.net/

i tag click event is not working in internet explorer 11 it's perfectly working in chrome and edge.
can any one help me for this problem why it's not working internet explorer 11..?

Comment: Does anything show up on the console? Any errors at all?

Comment: Probably has to do with the tag type `i`, maybe put a span around it and put the `onclick` on the span ?

Comment: What doesn't work? Is the event called at all? As mentioned above, do you see any errors?

Comment: @DBS in console i am not getting any error

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy i just want to know i tag click event fir in internet exploere or not..?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy i try but still it's not working

Comment: Why are you binding the click event to the `i` instead of the `button`? Buttons are things designed to be clicked on. Italic "text" is not!

Comment: @Quentin  i tried it but once the button is clicked then after that button not coming

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `<button>` tag to `<div>` tag. Code as bleow

```
 <div class="btn cms-btn-contorls">
            <i class="fas fa-play" onclick="playBannerVideo(this);"></i> 
        </div>
```